# Python: How can I store float and string types into one matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am reading csv file via pandas. The file contains both digits and text data. How can I store such data only into one numpy matrix ?

Comment: What kind of text data is that? Pandas `DataFrame` objects can contain text.

Comment: What's a `python matrix`?

Comment: Thanks for help.
Text data contains people names and so on. dtype of that data is Object.

Comment: I mean numpy matrix.

Comment: Have you read about `numpy` structured arrays, with compound `dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj I am little bit familiar with numpy structured array. But is there such kind of matrix ?

Answer (score 1):

A common way of constructing a structured array:

```
In [36]: arr = np.empty((2,), dtype='U10,int')
In [37]: arr
Out[37]: array([('', 0), ('', 0)], dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Or fill with data using a list of tuples:

```
In [38]: arr = np.array([('one',1),('Two',2)], dtype='U10,int')
In [39]: arr
Out[39]: array([('one', 1), ('Two', 2)], dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [40]: arr.shape
Out[40]: (2,)
```

The 1d array can be reshaped to 2d (and repeated or tiled or stacked to make larger nd arrays):

```
In [41]: arr.reshape(2,1)
Out[41]: 
array([[('one', 1)],
       [('Two', 2)]], dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

It can also be turned into a `np.matrix`, though I don't know why anyone would want to do that:

```
In [42]: np.matrix(arr)
Out[42]: matrix([[('one', 1), ('Two', 2)]], dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [43]: _.shape
Out[43]: (1, 2)
In [44]: __['f0']
Out[44]: matrix([['one', 'Two']], dtype='<U10')
```

Fields are accessed by name, not as columns.  There's a fundamental break between the dimensions recorded by the shape, and the components of the records defined by the `dtype`.